# Setting focus on textbox causes CSS overflow

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have a textbox that I set the focus to depending on some operations by the user. After do so the CSS for the page is thrown off; page shifts to the left. Below is the CSS involved:

```
width: 960px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top: 20px;
background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat;
```

Any clues as to what is happening and how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post your full code or at least a code snippet that represents your error please?

Comment: There is not actually an error, more so on postback the page content shifts to the left after doing the following: textbox.focus().

Comment: When I say error I wanted to mean the not-expected behaviour that you are getting. Without a code that reproduces it, it would be impossible to help you.

Comment: I posted the CSS in the question that seems to attribute to the issue and the code that causes the issue is what I just mentioned above; "textbox.focus()". If this "focus" event is never called the problem does not ever happen.

Comment: Update: After utilizing the developer tools in IE started looking at the code I provided in my question and after the "focus()" it still remains the same, however, I decided on a whim to remove the "overflow:hidden" and then add it back. The seemingly restores the page to the correct format, which is weird. It is almost like the on "focus()" the overflow settings are being dropped during the postback or not really applied. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I have to do more investigation into why, but the following resolved my issue. Adding a meta tag http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible".

There was a similar issue discussed here as well 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1485816.aspx?Scriptmanager+SetFocus+set+s+focus+but+I+can+t+type

Hope this helps anyone running into this issue. Additionally, the using the meta tag works no matter if you are utilizing the ScriptManager's SetFocus method or the Page/Control focus method.